# DataContract Attributes being ignored

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, datacontract

Im not sure why but whenever I try to add a [DataContract] attribute, its ignored as in the example below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;


[DataContract]
public partial class Employee
{
    [DataMember]
    private int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

I add DataMember onto a private property such as in EmployeeId and when I call a get with fiddler it doesn't get serialized.

I've also tried using [IgnoreDatamember] attribute and whatever I try to ignore is serialized anyway.

I have the "using System.Runtime.Serialization;" so I am unsure if there is anything I am missing to get these attributes working.

Comment: what serializer are you using?

Comment: The default System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer

Comment: That's really weird. Are you able to repro this in a standalone app?

Comment: I got it to start working, just needed to do a clean I guess. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the attribute DataMember to all properties you want to be serialized.
If you need to serialize it, add the attribute to the class:

```
[Serializable, DataContract]
public partial class Employee
{
...
}
```

This link can help: [SerializableAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx)